# How to debug assembly (intel86-64) using gdb?

Tags: debugging, assembly, gcc, gdb, x86-64

How can I debug .asm file on linux, I tried every suggestion on the web but nothing worked.

my file contents are similar to:

[image]

For example:
Here they are requesting .o file which I don't/can't have

https://ncona.com/2019/12/debugging-assembly-with-gdb/

Comment: See GDB tips at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  Source-level debugging is barely useful at all for asm; just use disassembly mode.  (`disas` instead of `list`, or use `layout reg` to highlight registers that change as you `stepi`.)

Comment: Do not post pictures of code!  Also, what assembler are you programming for?  And how do you assemble and link your code?

Comment: If you really tried `every suggestion on the web`, then it's unlikely anyone here can tell you something you don't already know.

Comment: If you've managed to build your code into an executable then everything about `.o` files is irrelevant: start the tutorial from the point where it says `gdb example`.  If you haven't managed to build your code, then that is what your question should really focus on; explain what you tried and what the result was.